# How to make old 4:3 video content into 16:9 with crop/zoom and slight stretch?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, handbrake

I have old video cam footage in 4:3 format that I'd like to have play better on modern 16:9 screens, specifically I'd like to:

- Crop/"Zoom" the video "a little" (cutting a tiny bit, maybe 10-15%, of the top and bottom of the video off)
- Stretch the video "a tiny bit" (maybe 10%) - this will of course can ruin the footage so would like to only stretch the video a tiny bit
- Still keep a bit of a border on the sides (since I don't want to stretch or crop the video too much)

I'll still keep the original files too, but would like a version that just plays slightly nicer natively in 16:9. And I'd like to use free software like ffmpeg or Handbrake.

I've found guides on how to crop and how to stretch the videos independently but I'm fearing having to re-encode the videos twice loses quality and takes a lot of time, so I'd like to do it all in one go.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

HandBrake GUI is a good place to start.

For this example I make the assumption that you are transcoding a 640x480 4:3 interlaced video. As for your hardware capabilities, we'll use a lower complexity preset with option for higher one.

1. Open HandBrake and drag/drop input file on source line or window.
2. From the Presets select General/HQ 480p Surround (low) or Matroska/H.265 MKV 480p30 (high)
3. On the Dimensions tab, change Cropping from Automatic to Custom.
4. Enter 30 in Top and 30 in bottom to start with. You can adjust these later to suit your preferences.
5. Change Resolution Limit to None
6. You can keep Anamorphic at Automatic with Optimal size checked .
7. The Scaled size should read 640, 420. These numbers represent the original width, height - cropping. In this case 640 -left-right - 640-0-0 = 640 width. And 480 - top - bottom = 480 - 30 - 30 = 420 height.
8. Uncheck the Automatic Aspect Ratio.
9. You requested some stretching so we'll calculate for a 16:10 aspect ratio.
   This is an older but common enough ratio. 16:10 = 16/10 = 1.6 (if you decide to try 16:9 use 1.78).
10. For the Display size we calculate based on the target ratio. Our scaled height is 420 * target ratio = 420 * 1.6 = 672. Always round up to the next even number.
    Enter 672 into Display Size. Don't worry that the numbers for pixel aspect ratio change.
11. Click Preview. You will see a visual video frame using the new dimensions.
12. Uncheck the Show Crop adjustments to show more of the video. Move the slider left or right to see if the cropping is good for you. Use Live Preview for 1 minute to generate a preview clip. The clip will be in the same output folder as the Save As .. file name_preview.
13. To change the cropping, check the Show Crop adjustments. Enter new numbers for top, bottom (maybe left, right?).
14. When you are satisfied with the output, close the Preview window. If you have changed the crop numbers in Preview, you will note the new numbers and scaling have been automatically adjusted. But you need to manually fix the Display Size. Repeat from step 10.
15. On the Video Tab you will see the defaults are constant quality 18 (CQ), and a peak frame rate of 30 fps. You might adjust the CQ down to 17 (lower = higher quality, larger file size) or up. There are many other discussions on this site regarding video encoding parameters.
16. On the Audio Tab you likely have a mono, maybe stereo input source. Remove the second entry by clicking the small circled x to the right.If the original is PCM or WAV or MP3 then choose Codec AAC bitrate 192 for stereo, 96 for mono.
17. On the subtitle tab, click Clear. On the Chapters tab, uncheck Create Chapters marker.
18. In the Save As.. choose ouput path and file name. To permanently change the output path use Tools/Preferences/Output Files.
19. Click Start Encode.
20. If you like the final results, save the preset for future use. Presets/Add Preset. Enter name. Adjust selection behavior Audio to match your choice, Subtitles, uncheck Foreign Audio Scan. Add.

Hope this guide helps you!

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.